# ViewPager with TextView shows strange results

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager and a TextView,Something weird is happening.
I have an array of Images in my code,and an array of String in String

```
  <string-array name="helper_text">
        <item>first</item>
        <item>second</item>
        <item>third</item>
        <item>fourth</item>
    </string-array>
```

and this is my xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.toyberman.tmdb.HelpActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/help_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/tv_help"
        android:layout_below="@+id/help_pager"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my java code

```
package com.toyberman.tmdb;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
        //finding view pager
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.help_pager);

        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_help, menu);
        return true;
    }


    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private String [] text;

        private Integer[] images = {
                R.drawable.first, R.drawable.second
                , R.drawable.third, R.drawable.fourth
        };

        public ImagePagerAdapter() {
            this.text = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.helper_text);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

            TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_help);
            tv.setText(text[position]);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(
                    decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),images[position],500, 500));


            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);

            return imageView;
        }

    }

}
```

The problem is that the strings from the String array doesn't correspond to the image. the first image should be the  "first" string,but i see "second" instead.

Thank you!

Comment: `instantiateItem` will actually be invoked on the both the first and second items, even if only the first item is visible.

Comment: so how can i solve this ?

Comment: Why are you always adding at index 0?

Comment: Where is the code for retrieving the strings?  Are you starting the string array index at zero, or are you starting the string array index at one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On **InstantiateItem**, the `int position` parameter is the position of the item that is being rendered and **NOT** the position of the currently focused item. You can do `((ViewPager) container).getCurrentItem()` to get the current item.

Hope this helps.